# what is mean "Winfield Hill is by inclination an electronics circuit-design guru" in Chinese

Tags: translation, meaning

The original text is

```
Winfield Hill is by inclination an electronics circuit-design guru. After dropping out of the Chemical Physics graduate
program at Harvard University, and obtaining an E.E. degree, he began his engineering career at Harvard’s Electronics
Design Center. After 7 years of learning electronics at Harvard he founded Sea Data Corporation, where he spent 16 years
designing instruments for Physical Oceanography. In 1988 he was recruited by Edwin Land to join the Rowland Institute
for Science. The institute subsequently merged with Harvard University in 2003. As director of the institute’s Electronics
Engineering Lab he has designed some 500 scientific instruments. Recent interests include high-voltage RF (to 15 kV),
high-current pulsed electronics (to 1200 A), low-noise amplifiers (to sub-nV and pA), and MOSFET pulse generators.
```

Winfield Hill is an electronics circuit-design guru. I translate it to Chinese is "Winfield Hill是电子电路设计专家"。

But "Winfield Hill is by inclination an electronics circuit-design guru" means
Winfield Hill天生就是电子电路设计专家 or Winfield Hill根据自己的意愿想成为电子电路设计专家？但又觉得某人天生就是某方面的专家这种说法不太合乎情理，因为没有人天生就是专家。

So how to translate it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inclination means: a feeling of wanting to do something, a tendency to do something

So here, it can be translated to “Winfield Hill想成为电子电路设计专家”

Comment: Can you say where you find inclination definition? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Winfield Hill is by inclination an electronics circuit-design guru - 基於**性向**, Winfield Hill 是一位電子線路設計的領袖/大家.

Inclination - **An attitude of mind** especially one that favors one alternative over others = 態度/個性上的傾向 = 趨向/性向/心向.

- He was a loner by nature and by inclination. - 根據天性与**性向**他都是一個孤独的人/不合群的人/独立自主的人。

Note that I think the sentence should be changed/modified to:

Winfield Hill became an electronics circuit-design guru by inclination - 經由**性向/心向/本心**, Winfield Hill 成為一位電子線路設計的領袖/大家.

- He is a teacher by occupation but a philosopher by inclination. 他的职业是教师，但他的**本心**是成为哲学家。

Comment: Winfield Hill became an electronics circuit-design guru by inclination 是不是可以翻译为Winfield Hill发自内心想成为电子电路设计专家？

Comment: Yes, I think you can.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, "by inclination" indicates that Winfield Hill probably has another, a different, profession, but he likes circuit design. Or they might have written, "by training and by inclination."

If you do something "by inclination" you do it because you like it.

Winfield Hill is by inclination an electronics circuit-design guru.
温菲尔德·希尔作为一位电子电路设计大师，他很喜欢这份工作。

Comment: I update my question that add original text, I think translate it to "温菲尔德·希尔作为一位电子电路设计大师，他很喜欢这份工作。" is not very accurate.